# Amazon API. Sales Volume of product. Not top sellers, but actual volume. Pull Volume *creatively?

Tags: amazon-mws

Amazon has its TOP 100 sellers by category, and by subcategory and that is all fine and well.  But as a Seller on Amazon, if I spend $100,000 to buy a product at Wholesale, and that product is number 1, or number 10, or number 100 on the TOP 100 in its category, HOW can I determine if that 100,000 will sell in a day, a week, a month or three months?

Does the API expose orders by day?  Sales Volume?  Is there any empirical data available?  Does the API expose enough data to arrive at "logical conclusion" or "reasonable expectation"

I need to have a strong sense of how much I should buy from our wholesaler.   I I am most interested in is the Grocery Category,

http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Grocery-Gourmet-Food/zgbs/grocery/ref=zg_bs_nav_0

Thank you in advance for any thoughtful guidance.

Answer (score 1):

**Q: HOW can I determine if that 100,000 will sell in a day, a week, a month or three months?**

**A: You cannot.**

It will remain Amazon's secret how many sales a product had and how exactly those TOP 100 lists are calculated. The AWS API does not export anything in terms of sales, MWS will only allow you to get *your own* sales figures.

**Q: Does the API expose enough data to arrive at "logical conclusion" or "reasonable expectation"**

**A: Not through the AWS alone.**

If, however, you have your own sales figures (through MWS) *and* know their position in the top 100 *and* you're not competing with other merchants on those products, you could *then* try to interpolate.

You have Top 5: 1000 sales
   You have Top 57: 170 sales

You can guess how many sales the top 10 product might be getting:

- Linear distribution of sales figures would suggest 16 sales less per rank, leaving you with 980
- Exponential distribution of sales figures would give you something in the around 700, depending on the order of your exponential interpolation.

*Alternate approach: bribe an Amazon employee :)*